# Is "because" always a subordinating conjunction introducing a subordinate clause?

Tags: english, grammar, sentences, clauses, conjunctions

My grammar book says that a word like "because" is a subordinating conjunction, meaning that it is a word that can introduce a dependent clause. I know that a dependent clause contains its own subject and predicate. For instance, this would be a principal clause and a dependent clause in which the dependent clause uses "because" and has its own subject and predicate:

"I went to the store [because I wanted those tomatoes.]"

However, I know very well that "because" could be used in other ways. For instance, we could say,

"I made this choice [because of you!]"

How would we label "because" in this case? It's only introducing a prepositional phrase. It's not introducing a subordinate/dependent clause with its own subject/predicate.

Comment: _Because of_ is a bit of a special case, essentially a two-word preposition – but even without _of_, there are cases where _because_ is clearly not a subordinating conjunction in recent English, particularly online. [Because reasons.](https://americandialect.org/because-is-the-2013-word-of-the-year/)

Comment: There are also other multi-word prepositions in English, e.g. "instead of", "rather than", "next to".

Comment: "Because" is not actually a subordinator at all, but a preposition. "Because of" is best treated as a compound preposition.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. Or, simply, "Because!"